# Moving a mesh relative to the origin

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d

Noobie: I can build and draw a mesh (loaded from an STL file), scale it appropriately and center the mesh on the screen, but I can't seem to move the mesh relative to the origin. Often a mesh's coords are, say, all in the +ve octant, so I want to move it so its center is on the origin, then I can spin it round.

I'm doing something wrong because whenever I move the mesh the origin moves with it. Can anyone save my brain and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h); 
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); 

    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45f, (float)w / (float)h, 0.1f, 5f * fMesh_Z_Extent;

    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, 0 - (2.5f * fMesh_Z_Extent));

    float f1, f2, f3;

    // set f1, f2, f3 to move centre of model to sit on the origin
    // this works perfectly, but the origin has moved with the mesh! Grrrr. 

    gl.glTranslatef(f1, f2, f3);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
    }

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // initialise mesh here

    gl.glColor4f(8f, 255f, 128f, 1f);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, Global.indices.length,
                  GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, Global.indexBuffer);

    gl.glRotatef(3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Disable the vertices buffer.
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean the origin has moved? The origin (0,0,0) is just a point in space which never moves. Are you meaning some part of your mesh you are calling the origin?

Comment: Sorry I need to describe it better... The mesh is more or less a cube, from 0,0,0 to about 130,130,130 (so the mesh touches the origin at one corner). The mesh is appearing perfectly centered on the screen, but the glRrotatef makes it spin on the corner which touches the origin, not on the center of the mesh's mass (about 65,65,65).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to rotate and translate in the opposite order. Matrix multiplications in OpenGL work the opposite of how we intuitively think of them. If you want to move your object to the origin and then rotate it, you need to first glRotate and then glTranslate - yeah... wierd huh.

I would put the glTranslate into the onDrawFrame and just do it every frame.

edit: ah... you want it to display with the corner at the origin but rotate around 65,65,65? Then you need to translate it -65, rotate, then translate 65 to get it back. This will make the center of rotation around the center of the object.

You should also have a glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix around these calls too.

Comment: OMG. Praise the Lord. Praise iforce2d anyway. I thank you. I had tried translate/rotate/translate back and was still failing... in fact all this time I had been doing translate / drawelements / rotate / translate back. Just put the translates immediately before and after the rotate and it works exactly as intended. I thank you again. Re push/pop, is that still needed with just one mesh on view at a time?

Comment: Without a push/pop, everything you draw after this will also be rotated around 65,65,65 as well. You may be loading the identity matrix or setting the view somewhere, but it's not in the code you posted so I'm just saying to be sure.

Comment: You're right, I don't plan to put anything else in the view right now, but who knows. Do it right now and I won't have to throw myself on your mercy next time :/ Many thanks for the help.